# Is there a canonical way of terminating a thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to force threads termination in python: I don't want to set an event and wait until the thread checks it and exits. I'm looking for a simple solution like `kill -9`. Is this possible to do that without dirty hacks like operating with private methods etc.?

Comment: No, it isn't.  There is no supported way to kill a thread from outside the thread.  The reason is that there's no way to know what resources that thread may have locked. The only way to write a correct program is to have threads end when they themselves know it is safe to end.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I suspect you're right, but want to see some approval like a piece of language specification etc.

Comment: Wouldn't the lack of a method in the stdlib be enough?

Comment: @NedBatchelder heh :-) makes sense

Comment: Not an answer: You could try running your code using `multiprocessing` if possible and terminate the thread-like object when needed.

Comment: While the following is about Java, the same reasoning applies here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind your code running about ten times slower, you can use the `Thread2` class implemented below. An example follows that shows how calling the new `stop` method should kill the thread on the next bytecode instruction.

```
import threading
import sys

class StopThread(StopIteration): pass

threading.SystemExit = SystemExit, StopThread

class Thread2(threading.Thread):

    def stop(self):
        self.__stop = True

    def _bootstrap(self):
        if threading._trace_hook is not None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot run thread with tracing!')
        self.__stop = False
        sys.settrace(self.__trace)
        super()._bootstrap()

    def __trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        if self.__stop:
            raise StopThread()
        return self.__trace


class Thread3(threading.Thread):

    def _bootstrap(self, stop_thread=False):
        def stop():
            nonlocal stop_thread
            stop_thread = True
        self.stop = stop

        def tracer(*_):
            if stop_thread:
                raise StopThread()
            return tracer
        sys.settrace(tracer)
        super()._bootstrap()

################################################################################

import time

def main():
    test = Thread2(target=printer)
    test.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    test.stop()
    test.join()

def printer():
    while True:
        print(time.time() % 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `Thread3` class appears to run code approximately 33% faster than the `Thread2` class.

Answer (score 0):

Threads end when they do.

You can *signal* a thread that you want it to terminate ASAP, but that assumes collaboration of the code running in a thread, and it offers no upper bound guarantee for when that happens.

A classic way is to use a variable like `exit_immediately = False` and have threads' main routines periodically check it and terminate if the value is `True`. To have the threads exit, you set `exit_immediately = True` and call `.join()` on all threads. Obviously, this works only when threads are able to check in periodically.

Comment: It is similar to `stop = threading.Event()`; in the main thread: `stop.set()`; in a thread that should stop: `if stop.is_set(): exit` but the OP don't want to use it

Comment: I noted, that I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require code collaboration with events and other sync. objects.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to just be able to let the program terminate at its end without caring about what happens to some threads, what you want is `daemon` threads.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon):

> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are
>   left.

Example usage program:

```
import threading
import time

def test():
  while True:
    print "hey"
    time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target=test)
t.daemon = True # <-- set to False and the program will not terminate
t.start()
time.sleep(10)
```

---

Trivia: `daemon` threads are referred to as `background` threads in .Net.