# How to limit function execution time in python multithreading environment?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a script which runs quite a lot of concurrent threads (at least 200). Every thread does some quite complex evaluations, which can take unpredictably lot of time. The evaluation method is implemented in C and I can't change it. I want to limit the method execution time for every thread. Please advise.

Comment: How does this question differ from your [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222349/is-there-a-canonical-way-of-terminating-a-thread-in-python)?

Comment: @DavidRobinson That's another task. I do not want to terminate the thread. It must postprocess a partial evaluation result.

Comment: I thought you said that you can't modify the evaluation. If it can't be modified, how can it return a partial result?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Each thread follows some iteration rules calling the evaluation method every iteration. So we have a list of evaluation results. At the end the thread must postprocess the list even if it doesn't contain all results.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, you haven't given us much of a context, and almost no idea of what you are looking for. Are there synchronization issues? data races? Is the evaluation method the bottleneck? or do you have code that is slowing things down? Are you trying to speed-up the code? [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your problem, it might be a good case for using multiprocessing instead of multithreading. Multiprocessing will allow you to make use of all the available resources on the system - and then some, if you're not careful.

Threads don't actually run in parallel, so unless you're doing a lot of waiting for I/O or something like that, it would make more sense to call it from a separate process. You could use the [Python multiprocessing library](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) to call it from a Python script, or you could use a wrapper written in C and use some form of [interprocess communication](http://docs.python.org/library/ipc.html). The second option will avoid the overhead of launching another Python instance just to run some C code.

You could call time.sleep (or perform other tasks and check the system clock for elapsed time), and then check for results after the desired interval, permitting any processes that haven't finished to continue running while you make use of the results. Or, if you don't care at that point, you can send a signal to kill the process.

Comment: the OP says that the calculations are in C. C extensions can release GIL so all CPU cores can be used without multiprocessing

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to run 200 processes on the system at once, especially if they are CPU intensive. It would be better to run them in batches, or you will be introducing additional overhead as they all vie for available CPU time and memory.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastion: That makes more sense. Still, you wouldn't want to run 200 of the things at once.

Comment: @EdColvin Your idea about checking for intermediate results after the desired interval is good for me. But multiprocessing is not good for me. The only problem left is how to shut down a thread which execution time exceeds the limit.